# How do I Cluster event data into similar groups

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

In order to cluster the event log data, I have tried both K means and hierarchical techniques. However, I have not been able to get a proper output. It is necessary to group the data based on similar event
I'm using K-means

```
clustering_score = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, init = 'random', random_state = 42)
    kmeans.fit(X)
    clustering_score.append(kmeans.inertia_)
 kmeans= KMeans(n_clusters = 5, random_state = 42)
 kmeans.fit(X)
```

An example of complaint handling event data is as follows:

| Case ID | Activity | Source |
| --- | --- | --- |
| case 1 | register request | P1 |
| case 1 | decide | A2 |
| case 2 | pay | C5 |
| case 2 | check ticket | B1 |
| case 3 | pay | C3 |

As a result, we are now grouping the similar case ids and creating a group for them
I tried but I couldn't form clusters

Desired output:

| Case ID | Clusters |
| --- | --- |
| case 1 | cluster 0 |
| case 1 | cluster 0 |
| case 2 | cluster 1 |
| case 2 | cluster 1 |
| case 3 | cluster 2 |

Any suggestions that I can create clusters as shown in desired output with my data using python ? Thanks!

Comment: You first might want to consider what you, the subject expert, would consider makes events similar.  How would you manually group these and why?